# Is this construction algebraically closed?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question, field-theory, abelian-groups

On the tetration forum Tommy1729 proposed a new kind of number :

http://math.eretrandre.org/tetrationforum/showthread.php?tid=1036

Too avoid deletion or changes of that post , I copy it here :

---

Spiral Numbers

The idea is simplest when thinking in terms of polar coordinates.

For a,c > 0 and b,d real , the complex numbers satisfy

(a,b) (c,d) = (ac , b + d mod 2 pi)

The idea of spiral numbers is

(a,b)(c,d) = (ac , b + d)

So far for products.

The sum for spiral numbers is defined by

X + Y = ln( exp(X) exp(Y) ).

So it comes down to finding a good ln and exp.

My first guess is ln(a,b) =

( | ln(sqrt(a^2 + b^2)) | , b / e )

Where |*| is the absolute value.
And the exp is just the inverse.

For X^Y we use exp( ln X * Y ).

I wonder how the algebra works out.

Is this a good idea ?

I wonder what you think.

---

My question is :

Is this construction algebraicly closed ?

I think so because it seems addition , multiplication and powers are well defined.

I assume it implies that substraction , division , sqrt , ln and exp are Well defined too. And therefore also solving polynomials.

Related is the question

What are the solution to $x + 1 = 0$ and $y^2 = x$ ?

And how many solutions exist ??

Let a polynomial $P_n(z)$ of degree $n$ have spiral coëfficiënts.
Does the equation $P_n(z) = 0$ have exactly $n$ solutions ?

Can we represent this by matrices ??

What do you think of this construction ?

Comment: ? The tag algebraic closure Gets replaced by field theory automatically. Is that normal ?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't even well-defined, because the function $\ln$ is not a bijection (or even always well-defined!) so $\exp$ (and hence $+$) are not always well-defined.  When $a^2+b^2=1$, the first coordinate of $\ln(a,b)$ is $0$, so it does not give an element of the set; maybe you are saying that $\ln(a,b)=0$ for such $(a,b)$ (with $0$ being a special element which is not represented in the form $(a,b)$), but then you still have the problem that $\ln$ is not injective, since there are many such $(a,b)$ that would map to $0$.  Even ignoring this, $\ln$ is neither surjective nor injective: if $(c,d)$ is in the range of $\ln$ and $d\geq 1$, then $c>1+\ln d$, and $\ln(a,0)=\ln(1/a,0)$ for all $a$.

Putting aside the definition of addition given in the question, there is *no* definition of addition that can combine with that definition of multiplication (together with a $0$ element) to give a field of characteristic $0$ (or indeed, any ring in which $2\neq 0$).  For the only element which satisfies $x^2=1$ is $1=(1,0)$ itself, so this means $1=-1$, so $0=2$.  In addition, even if you did give it an addition that made it a field of characteristic $2$, it would not be algebraically closed, because it contains no roots of unity besides $1$.

Comment: Nice answer. Can the problems be fixed with another def of ln ?

Comment: The second paragraph of my answer addresses that.